# How do I preserve the changed color and still display it after the page is submitted.. I want to use PHP sessions or cookies

Tags: php, html-table

I want to store a session variable and echo it. I don't know how to do this.
At the moment I have the following code:

```
<script>
  function changecolor(obj)
  {
    obj.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
  }
</script>


<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td id="glow1" bgcolor="green" onclick="changecolor(this)" >8-9  /td><br>
    <td id="glow2" bgcolor="green" onclick="changecolor(this)" >9-10 /td><br>
    <td id="glow3" bgcolor="green" onclick="changecolor(this)" >10-11 /td><br>
  </tr>
</table>

<form action="sample.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="confirm">
</form>
```

Comment: U could add an ajax call that posts the chosen colour to a PHP script and store it in a session from there

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What happened to all of your tags?  Most are missing `<` or `>`.  Also, please use *code blocks* to format your question on Stack Overflow.  There are plenty of tutorials and answered questions already out there on the topic, so what have you tried and what hasn't worked (specifically) out of that research?

Comment: @DarkBee Thank you for your response. I am new to ajax concept. I learnt how to make get/post calls now. Thanks again. cheers.

Comment: @BLaZuRE I didn't know how to format it. Thanks for your advice.I will use code blocks from now on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JS :

```
function changeColor(color) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: { 
                        'color': color
                    },
                url: '/url/to/script.php',
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    $('#table td').css('background-color',data);
                }
            });

}
```

index.php :

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if (isset($_SESSION['color'])) {
        $color = $_SESSION['color'];
   }else{
        $color = '#FFFFFF';
   }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="table" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td onclick="changeColor('#FF0000');" bgcolor="<?php echo $color;?>">Turn red</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="changeColor('#00FF00');" bgcolor="<?php echo $color;?>">Turn green</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="changeColor('#0000FF');" bgcolor="<?php echo $color;?>">Turn blue</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
     </body>
</html>
```

script.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['color'] = $_POST['color'];
    echo $_POST['color'];
?>
```

Comment: Do I have to post the <table> elements along with the color ,because the color change is taking place on any of the <td> elements. Basically my aim is to capture the present state of the page(assuming that a <td> with content 8-9 is clicked and the background color of tht element is changed to desired color and the other two slots 9-10 and 10-11 background color is same as the are not clicked) and post it back to the php so that the user can see which <td> is clicked after submitting.It can not be done with out using ajax because the page reloads after every post.Hope you get my point

Comment: updated, demo @http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/n4m-kes, just hit run and reload and run again